# cannot boot ubuntu or windows

Tags: dual-boot

I tried to install ubuntu 20.04 along with windows 10, yet an error occurred while installing ubuntu. Now I cannot boot anything. It automatically drive me to ASUS uefi bios. I have the following report. Can anyone help me??

```
boot-repair-4ppa171                                              [20220215_1022]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda6 starts 
                       at sector -396314624. But according to the info from 
                       fdisk, sda6 starts at sector 3898652672.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32784 of /dev/sdc1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

sdd1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       exfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on sda5
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on sdb1

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] from NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, focal, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled.

BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,0003
Boot0001* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.S.T.2.0.0.0.V.X.0.0.0.-.1.E.S.1.6.4....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .4.Z.6.Z.J.A.J.2........BO..NO........o.K.I.N.G.S.T.O.N. .S.U.V.4.0.0.S.3.7.2.4.0.G....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.5.2.0.B.6.7.7.8.6.5.0.0.1.3.C. . . . ........BO..NO........i.W.D. .M.y. .B.o.o.k. .2.5.E.D. .1.0.3.1....................A.............................6..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.3.5.5.1.4.8.3.0.5.7.5.A.3.1.4.2........BO..NO........Y.G.e.n.e.r.i.c. .F.l.a.s.h. .D.i.s.k. .8...0.7....................A.............................&..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.C.E.9.6.5.5.D.1........BO
Boot0002* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.T.S.S.T.c.o.r.p. .C.D.D.V.D.W. .S.H.-.2.2.4.G.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.S.2.C.Y.6.H.A.0.3.3.1.8.Q. . . . . . ........BO
Boot0003* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 8.07, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1a,0x0)/USB(0,0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1a16a546,0x800,0x1daf800)..BO

85fa9d77b929ec4231aba29476574eb6   sda6/BOOT/fbx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   sda6/BOOT/mmx64.efi
fa1bf1a7f90a852abe0bdbd089b7f1b0   sda6/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   sda6/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda6/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda6/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdd : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda6    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdd1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda6    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdd1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda5    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda6    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdd1    : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdd

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x07e48429
      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1             2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2          1026048 2883024895 2881998848   1.4T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3       2883026942 3907028991 1024002050 488.3G  5 Extended
sda5       2883026944 3898650623 1015623680 484.3G 83 Linux
sda6  *    3898652672 3899138047     485376   237M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sda7       3899140096 3907028991    7888896   3.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
Disk sdb: 223.58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x07e48421
      Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1            2048 467097275 467095228 222.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sdb2       467097600 468856831   1759232   859M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
Disk sdc: 14.86 GiB, 15938355200 bytes, 31129600 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x1a16a546
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdc1  *     2048 31129599 31127552 14.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk sdd: 10.94 TiB, 12000138625024 bytes, 23437770752 sectors
Disk identifier: 4BC6DBF4-039A-4955-B359-6631A2F05450
      Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
sdd1   2048 23437768703 23437766656 10.9T Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA ST2000VX000-1ES1:;
1:1049kB:525MB:524MB:ntfs::;
2:525MB:1476GB:1476GB:ntfs::;
3:1476GB:2000GB:524GB:::;
5:1476GB:1996GB:520GB:ext4::;
6:1996GB:1996GB:249MB:fat32::boot, esp;
7:1996GB:2000GB:4039MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
sdb:240GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA KINGSTON SUV400S:;
1:1049kB:239GB:239GB:ntfs::;
2:239GB:240GB:901MB:ntfs::msftres;
sdc:15.9GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:15.9GB:15.9GB:fat32::boot, lba;
sdd:12.0TB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:WD My Book 25ED:;
1:1049kB:12.0TB:12.0TB::My Book:msftdata;

Free space (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1907729MiB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA ST2000VX000-1ES1:;
1:0.03MiB:1.00MiB:0.97MiB:free;
1:1407727MiB:1407728MiB:1.00MiB:free;
1:1907729MiB:1907729MiB:0.09MiB:free;
sdb:228937MiB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA KINGSTON SUV400S:;
1:0.03MiB:1.00MiB:0.97MiB:free;
1:228075MiB:228075MiB:0.16MiB:free;
1:228934MiB:228937MiB:2.59MiB:free;
sdc:15200MiB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:0.03MiB:1.00MiB:0.97MiB:free;
sdd:11444224MiB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:WD My Book 25ED:;
1:0.02MiB:1.00MiB:0.98MiB:free;
1:11444223MiB:11444224MiB:0.98MiB:free;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                     PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                 
├─sda1 ntfs     E486AC7286AC4740                     07e48429-01                          Δεσμευμένο από το σύστημα 
├─sda2 ntfs     AAEECAA4EECA67E1                     07e48429-02                          HDD                       
├─sda3                                               07e48429-03                                                    
├─sda5 ext4     35760074-c098-4aed-a6d5-6bf212886e2f 07e48429-05                                                    
├─sda6 vfat     7168-2024                            07e48429-06                                                    
└─sda7 swap     75ced76f-ed50-4ee6-b73e-a10b233dba1c 07e48429-07                                                    
sdb                                                                                                                 
├─sdb1 ntfs     D8E0B1F6E0B1DB48                     07e48421-01                                                    
└─sdb2 ntfs     DE46745046742C01                     07e48421-02                                                    
sdc                                                                                                                 
└─sdc1 vfat     70B6-30F2                            1a16a546-01                          UBUNTU 20_0               
sdd                                                                                                                 
└─sdd1 exfat    74CD-2A43                            9e486afa-2fad-4cc7-8ae9-7a11cc31e1aa My Book                   My Book

Mount points (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              468.9M   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2              715.8G  48% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda5              444.8G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sda6              228.1M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
/dev/sdb1               37.8G  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb2              421.5M  51% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2
/dev/sdc1                 12G  19% /cdrom
/dev/sdd1               47.7G 100% /mnt/boot-sav/sdd1

Mount options (filtered): ________________________________________________________________

/dev/sda1              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda2              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda5              rw,relatime
/dev/sda6              rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb1              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb2              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdc1              ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdd1              rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro

====================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   35760074-c098-4aed-a6d5-6bf212886e2f
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic   35760074-c098-4aed-a6d5-6bf212886e2f
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=35760074-c098-4aed-a6d5-6bf212886e2f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda6 during installation
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=75ced76f-ed50-4ee6-b73e-a10b233dba1c none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
1550.988285065 = 1665.360990208 boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
1378.015621185 = 1479.633006592 boot/vmlinuz                                   2
1378.015621185 = 1479.633006592 boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic                 2
1623.740856171 = 1743.478468608 boot/initrd.img                                2
1623.740856171 = 1743.478468608 boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic              2
1623.740856171 = 1743.478468608 boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18151 Aug 12  2021 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Aug 12  2021 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Aug 12  2021 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Aug 12  2021 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Aug 12  2021 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Aug 12  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Aug 12  2021 41_custom

===================== sda6/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 35760074-c098-4aed-a6d5-6bf212886e2f root hd0,msdos5 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdc1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sdd1

00000000  eb 76 90 45 58 46 41 54  20 20 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.v.EXFAT   .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000040  00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 f0 ff 74 05 00 00 00  |...........t....|
00000050  00 08 00 00 00 60 01 00  00 68 01 00 d1 9f ae 00  |.....`...h......|
00000060  05 00 00 00 43 2a cd 74  00 01 00 00 09 0b 01 80  |....C*.t........|
00000070  63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  33 c9 8e d1 8e c1 8e d9  |c.......3.......|
00000080  bc d0 7b bd 00 7c 88 16  6f 7c b4 41 bb aa 55 cd  |..{..|..o|.A..U.|
00000090  13 72 69 81 fb 55 aa 75  63 f6 c1 01 74 5e fe 06  |.ri..U.uc...t^..|
000000a0  02 7c 66 50 b0 65 e8 a6  00 66 58 66 b8 01 00 00  |.|fP.e...fXf....|
000000b0  00 8a 0e 6d 7c 66 d3 e0  66 89 46 e8 66 b8 01 00  |...m|f..f.F.f...|
000000c0  00 00 8a 0e 6c 7c 66 d3  e0 66 89 46 d8 66 a1 40  |....l|f..f.F.f.@|
000000d0  7c 66 40 bb 00 7e b9 01  00 66 50 e8 41 00 66 58  ||f@..~...fP.A.fX|
000000e0  66 40 bb 00 80 b9 01 00  e8 34 00 66 50 b0 78 e8  |f@.......4.fP.x.|
000000f0  5d 00 66 58 e9 09 01 a0  fc 7d eb 05 a0 fb 7d eb  |].fX.....}....}.|
00000100  00 b4 7d 8b f0 ac 98 40  74 0c 48 74 0e b4 0e bb  |..}....@t.Ht....|
00000110  07 00 cd 10 eb ef a0 fd  7d eb e6 cd 16 cd 19 66  |........}......f|
00000120  60 66 6a 00 66 50 06 53  66 68 10 00 01 00 b4 42  |`fj.fP.Sfh.....B|
00000130  b2 80 8a 16 6f 7c 8b f4  cd 13 66 58 66 58 66 58  |....o|....fXfXfX|
00000140  66 58 66 61 72 b1 03 5e  d8 66 40 49 75 d1 c3 66  |fXfar..^.f@Iu..f|
00000150  60 b4 0e bb 07 00 b9 01  00 cd 10 66 61 c3 42 00  |`..........fa.B.|
00000160  4f 00 4f 00 54 00 4d 00  47 00 52 00 0d 0a 52 65  |O.O.T.M.G.R...Re|
00000170  6d 6f 76 65 20 64 69 73  6b 73 20 6f 72 20 6f 74  |move disks or ot|
00000180  68 65 72 20 6d 65 64 69  61 2e ff 0d 0a 44 69 73  |her media....Dis|
00000190  6b 20 65 72 72 6f 72 ff  0d 0a 50 72 65 73 73 20  |k error...Press |
000001a0  61 6e 79 20 6b 65 79 20  74 6f 20 72 65 73 74 61  |any key to resta|
000001b0  72 74 0d 0a 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff  |rt..............|
000001c0  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
000001f0  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff 6c 8b 98 55 aa  |...........l..U.|
00000200




Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
sda5 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because legacy Windows detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

LegacyWindows detected. The boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda (ATA ST2000VX000-1ES1) disk!
Please set your BIOS in Legacy mode in order to start your Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, then type command [sudo update-grub] in order to add the Windows entry to your GRUB menu.
```

**EDIT**.

The error tha appears while Installing ubuntu is: ***Executing grub-install dev/sda6 failed. This is a fatal error.***

The message that appears when I try to fix the above error with boot repair is: ***LegacyWindows detected. THe boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. Are you sure you want to continue anyway?***
When I proceed, the reports that I have attached occured.

Also, sda5 is my main linux filesystem, sda6 is the EFI system and sda7 is the swap space. **When I had to pick the place for Device for boot loader installation I firstly picked the sda5, and afterwards and sda6.** Should I pick sda?

Comment: It would help if you told us what the error was when you installed Ubuntu. But we are where we are. Have you tried booting in to the firmware (normally F10 on boot) and selecting the boot options. It will normally give you an option to booth from a specific disk. If you boot in to /dev/sdc it should offer you a GRUB menu so that you can choose which OS to boot: Ubuntu or Windows. try that

Comment: I tried that, but no boot is performed in any disk. The error was something about the grub installation. I also used boot-repair and a new report has been created reporting this error.
Here is the link for the new report.  Also I should mention that in the process of partitioning the disk, I created and ext4, an EFI and a swap portion from an allocated disk. 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sg2H6pz9Kc_63Zs0UYSYk26yvXHy9UvJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, marking my answer down is not going to improve it! 

Looking at your disks, which on has the EFI boot partition on it? If its on SDC1 then the format should be FAT not vfat, and definitely not ext4. The part of the install program that write the EFI gets a bit picky about this. 

I am also a bit concerned about sda6 - is there an error in the partition table for this disk?

Comment: I recommend trying to boot using Super GRUB2 Disk. You can download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2/ Make sure you can unpack the ISO image on an external drive, like you would with the Ubuntu ISO

Comment: I believe I have understand the problem. I tried to install Linux UEFI while windows are on Legacy mode, that's why grub could not be installed. Yet, now I cannot enter windows either. I managed to enter grub through a Super Grub2 with a USB stick. And now what?!

Comment: Now you should make Windows installation media and boot from it to repair Windows. Or, better, reinstall it UEFI mode as any Windows or Linux should be in any UEFI hardware, i.e., any consumer line computer since 10 years ago. Then install Ubuntu properly in UEFI mode.